# Altium: Plane assignment for split planes

Tags: pcb, altium

How can I assign multiple nets to a single plane layer? I've assigned the ground plane to net GND in the layer stack manager. But how can I assign nets 1.5V, 3.3V and 5V to the power plane?

Comment: Split the plane, then double click on region to assign net.  See http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Internal+Power+and+Split+Planes#InternalPowerandSplitPlanes-AssigningaNettoaSplitPlane

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, int that case you shouldn't use a power plane, because it means you will have only one net to the entire plane. You should use a normal layer, and draw the power planes yourself using polygons.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign multiple nets to a single plane layer by drawing close shape with the drawing tool.

Here an example from my personnal current project:
[image]

The majority of the plane is 3.3 v but than I draw a close shape that connect  both of my 5 V. After you just got to double click the new shape and a menu will pop-up in AD 2015 that let you assign a Net to the split plane.